# GULP failed to install

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I tryed to install Gulp (under root acces) but it failed with this in log.

```
49 error error rolling back Error: Refusing to delete: /bin/gulp not in /lib/node_modules/gulp-cli
49 error error rolling back     at clobberFail (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:41:12)
49 error error rolling back     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:27:14)
49 error error rolling back     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:36:12
49 error error rolling back     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
49 error error rolling back  gulp-cli@1.2.1 { [Error: Refusing to delete: /bin/gulp not in /lib/node_modules/gulp-cli] code: 'EEXIST', path: '/bin/gu$
50 error Refusing to delete: /bin/gulp not in /lib/node_modules/gulp-cli
```

Comment: i think gulp is not missing in node_modules so suggest you to install gulp module and retry.

Comment: Wow, thanks installation of "gulp" instead of "gulp-cli" (found it on github page) works.